# Prevent child types from using parent type extension methods

Tags: c#

As an example, I have an several extension methods for converting strings and objects into decimals and int32

```
    public static decimal ToDecimal(this object o)
    {
         return Convert.ToString(o).ToDecimal();
    }

    public static decimal ToDecimal(this string s)
    {
         decimal d = decimal.TryParse(s, out d) ? d : 0;
         return d;
    }

    public static Int32 ToInt32(this object o) { //etc }
```

But I want to prevent chaining like such:

```
myobject.ToDecimal().ToDecimal();
```

or even

```
myobject.ToDecimal().ToInt32();
```

If the programmer wants to convert the decimal to int32, then I want him to use `Convert.ToInt32()` which may just be more efficient since the Convert.ToString part is omitted, and also has more features.

**How can I tell C# that only object can use the extension method and not decimal, int etc?**

Comment: Only way i can think of is to put your extension methods in a different namespace and include it only when needed. Of course you'd still get the issue in code files where it is included though.

Comment: We had the same issue certainly. Will now try to write down our findings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. This isn't an extension method issue so much as a general method parameter issue - it will always be valid when the argument can be converted to the method parameter type.

I can think of a few grotty hack-arounds:

```
public static decimal ToDecimal<T>(this T value) where T : class, new()
```

That would prevent you calling `ToDecimal().ToDecimal()` as `decimal` isn't a class; it would also prevent you calling `ToDecimal().ToString().ToDecimal()` as `string` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

I would suggest that it's not *really* an appropriate extension method though, to be honest. I would suggest taking more care over how your conversions are performed to start with, and only doing them in very appropriate situations. For example, your current extension method would allow you to convert between `double` and `decimal` inappropriately, which isn't a good idea. Under what circumstances do you *really* want to do this? Which types are you trying to convert?

Comment: I think it should be ok if I can restrict the method to only Object's use. Otherwise, I agree it's not safe.

Comment: @Jake: Personally I'd still be dubious even then. What types are you *actually* trying to convert?

Comment: If I must choose one type then it will be string. But many starts out as objects from the database.

Comment: @Jake: Why do you have many types which can be converted directly to decimal? I can understand having many types with decimal *properties*, but that's a different matter. I would also try to avoid string conversions as far as possible - and where they *are* required, you should consider whether they're meant to be from a user (in which case you should use their culture for parsing) or machine-readable (in which case use the invariant culture).

Comment: What I meant was the values taken from the database are of the type Object, and stay as Object throughout the lifetime of the application. It is a business requirement that each field can be a string or number. Of course in the "Class Object" sense this will not make sense, but at least the function is not fatal.

Comment: @Jake: But what's the *execution time* type of these fields? If they're decimals, they should presumably be boxed decimal values already.

Comment: You mean direct casting to decimal? But the DB columns are strings. It's a data entry program, without a lot of real time validations or computation. There is a "check for errors" and "generate cost report" button where all the data is processed, still, speed is not that critical at this stage yet.

Comment: @Jake: Okay, so if everything is a string, you should make it *explicitly* a string everywhere you can. I'd also suggest that *if at all possible* you change the DB columns to appropriate numeric types. Keeping everything as a string is a recipe for bad data.

Comment: Without a way to restrict, I most probably will omit the object extension anyway. I have already tried many times without success to enforce numeric types. But it's just not going to work out here. where I work. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem have also Microsoft in LINQ.
The provide `Count()` method on `IEnumarable<T>`. It iterates the whole sequence counting elements in it.

On the other side they have `IList<T>` which already have `Count` property on it and does not need the `Count()` extension method which is much more inefficient then the `Count` property.

They can not prohibit using it thus `IEnumerable<T>` is a base inetrface of `IList<T>`.
What they do is they make a type differentiation inside `Count()` extension method.

Something like this:

```
if (obejct is List) {return ((List)object).Count;}
else {...}
```

My advice is not to prohibit anything but to put optimal implementations behind all extension methods. You can analyze object type inside your extension methods and react optimally by skiping `ToString()` for decimal types when converted to int.

Comment: One more example of type checking is `ToArray()` extension method implementation on `IEnumerable<T>`. By the way type checking is generally a bad smell, but in this case I think you should make a compromise for user convenience.